# MS Reporting Services 2005 - Report Subscriptions Email only Occassionally Working

Tags: reporting-services

I have an internal customer that only receives his email report from MS Report Services 2005 about 30% of the time. It is not getting caught by a SPAM filter. The report takes about 2 minutes to run. Does Reporting Services give up after 60 seconds? How do I begin to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a subscription for yourself.  Have it mailed to you every 5 minutes for a couple of hours.  See what happens...?

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but I'm getting no email. I'll do the same thing to another report and see how it goes.

Comment: Any luck with the other report?

Comment: Nope. Still something off. Looking into some of the DNS / Mail Gateway type stuff now.  Some people are getting reports, some aren't. Seems to be tied to "region" (maybe mailbox servers). Will post a follow up when I figure it out.

Comment: Ends up going to have to call Microsoft on this one. Still have a few users with issues. All reports work for me, 100% of the time. I have checked the client-side and server-side SPAM filters.

Comment: you can use these tools here to fire a subscription on demand: http://ssrs-tools.com. Maybe more helpful than getting reports every 5 minutes?